# Deleting the m2m relationship instead of the the object itself in Django via REST API

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-rest-framework, django-signals

I have 3 models: `User`, `UserItem` (the m2m thourgh), and `Item`.

A `User` can create an `Item`. This automatically creates a `UserItem`.

A different `User` can see that `Item`, and add it to their own list of items, creating another `UserItem`.

If that first `User` wants to delete the `Item`, the other `User` won't be happy - it needs to stay, but appear gone for the initial `User`. However, if there's only one `User` still related to it, then the `Item` is safe to delete, and should be deleted to avoid filling the database with dead records.

This is how I think it should be handled:

1. `Item delete` call made to API from `User`
2. `Item` `pre_delete` checks if `item.user_set > 1`
3. If `True`, manually delete the `UserItem`, leave `Item` where it is. If `False`, delete the `Item`

This way `UserItem` isn't exposed via the API, and management for a client is simplified.

Is this the right/common way to go? How can it be done with Django? I'm unsure how to prevent `Item.delete()` from happening within `pre_delete` without raising an exception, but as this is expected behaviour raising an exception doesn't seem like the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I went with. It keeps the logic in the `model`, but the `view` gives it the current `user`.

I thought it best to keep out of `delete()` because an admin user should be able to delete an Item regardless of related users, and there is no simple way to access the current `user` within `delete()`.

Constructive criticism welcome!

#### models.py

```
class Item(TimeStampedModel):

    ...

    def delete_item_or_user_item(self, user):
    """
    Delete the Item if the current User is the only User related to it.
    If multiple Users are related to the Item, delete the UserItem.
    """
    if UserItem.objects.filter(item=self).count() > 1:
        UserItem.objects.filter(item=self, user=user).delete()
    else:
        self.delete()
```

#### views.py

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    ...

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        instance.delete_item_or_user_item(self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems fine to me. But instead of working with signals, you could override the `delete()` method on the Item model. See [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) for an example with the `save()` method. Your `delete()` method could be implemented likewise, i.e. that it wont call the `super()` when there are still other Users with a UserItem.

Answer (score 1):

From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects): "If you want customized deletion behavior, you can override the delete() method."

I think it's what you want:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if item.user_set > 1:
        return
    else:
        super(Item, self).delete(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" delete() method.
```

Comment: I still need to delete the `UserItem` (instead of return). I can't figure out how to do this - I know the Item ID, but I need to get the User ID, otherwise I can't delete the correct UserItem